# I need to do some PHP/MYSQL pagination but output the query results in a 3x3 table

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, html-table, sql-order-by

On my page I want to make a query to the database and paginate the results, so that they are in descending order based on the amount of people viewing the page at the current time. I want it to read left to right for the top three and then break to a new row and then read left to right again for the results four to six and so on and so on and so forth.

So I have the table laid out like this:

```
    <div class="popular1">
                            <table class="pop-table-thumb">
                                <tr  colspan="3">
                                <div class="pop-table-header">
                            Most popular
                                </div>
                            <br>
                            </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="pop-thumb">
                                            <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </table>

                        </div>
```

I know how to do basic pagination and listing the results from an assoc query like this for example:

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `something` FROM `something`");
    while ($assoc_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo '<p>', $assoc_array['something'] ,'</p>';
    }
```

so does anyone have any ideas on how I should go about this?

Comment: <img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/>  
  
this part is where i would have a link and the info from the db just to clarify

Comment: You're one of those people that think text is read more accurately when it's bold or what?

Comment: answers not criticisms

Comment: Well I'm one of those people who could've answered but refuses to read an entire all-caps or all-bold chunk of text.

Comment: is that better m'lord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create 3 wide rows, by using a counter and [modulus `%`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

```
<div class="popular1">
    <table class="pop-table-thumb">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><div class="pop-table-header">Most popular</div><br></td>
        </tr>
<?php
$counter = 1; // basic counter to be used in the while loop
while($row = .....){
if($counter%3 == 1){ // if modulus == 1 (ie. 1,4,7) start a row
    echo'<tr>';}

    // This is where you can change your data from your database
    echo '<td><div class="pop-thumb"><img class="img-thumb" src="Images/DefaultThumbnail.gif"/></div></td>';
    
if($row%3 == 0){   // if modulus == 0 (ie. 3,6,9) close the row
    echo'</tr>';}
    $counter++;} // increase the counter
?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thankyou very much... this was the method i was looking for exactly :)